# Fetch consumer count from RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am trying to fetch the total number of consumers for a particular queue in RabbitMQ. I wrote my code in C# using RabbitMQ client for .Net.

```
string user = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rmq_user"];
string pword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rmq_pass"];
string port = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rmq_port"];
string host = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rest_api_url"]).Host;
var factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.Uri = "amqp://" + user + ":" + pword + "@" + host + ":" + port;
using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
{
    using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        var consumerCount = ((RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase)(channel)).m_consumers;
    }
}
```

I am getting `var consumerCount = ((RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase)(channel)).m_consumers;` as 0. However I can see the consumers in the RabbitMQ web and I have made sure that the consumers do exist in that queue.
Is this the correct way to get the consumer count or I am doing something wrong? I know this can be done using RabbitMQ admin but I need to do it in C#.
Please let me know if I can give some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working as you have not specified the queue for which you want the consumers.

You can do it as follows:

```
 using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {

            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                var queueDeclareOK = channel.QueueDeclarePassive(QueueName);
                var consumerCount = queueDeclareOK.ConsumerCount;
            }
        }
```

Comment: channel.QueueDeclare(QueueName, true, false, false, null); will create a new queue or it will use the existing queue? Also will it dequeue any messages?

Comment: It will create a queue if it is not present. Otherwise it will not do anything. It will also not dequeue any messages

Comment: I get this exception for an existing queue: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=406, text="PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue 'ev.ae.se.q.automation.HR' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value 'ev.ae.se.x.fallout' of type 'longstr'", classId=50, methodId=10, cause=   But when I try with a non-existing queue, it creates the new queue and works without error second time also.

Comment: Then you can try `channel.QueueDeclarePassive(QueueName)` and try.

Answer (score 0):

See `IModal.ConsumerCount()` on [docs](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v3.6.9/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-3.6.9-client-htmldoc/html/type-RabbitMQ.Client.IModel.html#method-M:RabbitMQ.Client.IModel.ConsumerCount(System.String))

Answer (score 0):

In golang, there is a method called [QueueInspect](https://github.com/streadway/amqp/blob/e6b33f460591b0acb2f13b04ef9cf493720ffe17/channel.go#L837), it will return consumer count:

```
queue, err := channel.QueueInspect(queueName)
if err != nil {
    return errors.New("fail to inspect queue " + queueName + "err: " + err.Error())
}
fmt.Println("consumer count is ", queue.Consumers)
```